# 1140 CSS Grid not working on ipad

Tags: css, media-queries

I have used 1140px CSS Grid (cssgrid.net) to code this page: http://workaday.org/dev/static/

It's restructuring all content on 750px width instead of 767px, as a result it's not working on iPad.

Can someone please suggest what i have done wrong in this?

---

Update:

I changed max-width to 784px, and now it's working on 767px, there is a difference of 17px. But i am not able to find reason for this so far.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 767px)
```

That is not logic to me. so you can try with variations

```
@media only handheld and (max-width: 767px)
```

or

```
@media handheld and (max-width: 767px)
```

I don't have iPad, so I can't test it.

Comment: i did not understand your answer, my page is scaling so there is not issue with handheld or screen. Also i am using a grid system already tested on various devices. My issue is it's scaling on 750 width instead of 767px.

Comment: About that update: You changed max-width to 784px and now it's working. I realise why is that. It's because there is no device with resolution 767px. It's only 768px. So if you put max-width:768px instead max-width:784px, i think it will work also. In case you set max-width to 767px that will afect only devices with width below 767px (Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i already tried that, and it's not working below 784px. However demo files of cssgrid.net are working fine with 767px.